# Printing json data gives me undefined

Tags: javascript, json

```
var work={
    "title": ["test1", "test2"]

}

for(var x in work)
console.log(work.title[x]);
```

Why does it show me undefined in console

Comment: because your x === `'title'`

Comment: And why exactly you iterate over `work`, yet try to use iterator on `work.title`?

Comment: try `console.log(work[x][0])` to print `test1`. You can further iterate over `work[x]` or equivalently `work['title']` or `work.title` because it is an array. I hope with these usage you will understand the object is actually an associative array.

Comment: Can answer this very simply yourself by logging `work` in console and seeing what it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need print the titles you should:

```
var work = {
    "title": ["test1", "test2"]
}

for (var title of work.title) {
    console.log(title);
}
```

Or:

```
var work = {
    "title": ["test1", "test2"]
}

work.title.forEach(function(title) {
    console.log(title);
});
```

These are the more clean ways for javascript I guess, in the most of cases you didn't need use the array index.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var work = {
  "title": ["internship", "test"],
  "employer": ["sdc", "test"],
  "date": [2017, 2018],
  "location": ["Bouira", "Alger"],
  "description": ["Réalisation logiciel gestion park", "test"]
}

    // for...in
for (var key in work) {
  var value = work[key];
  console.log(value, '\n');

      // for...of
  for (var item of value) {
    console.log(item, '\n\n');
  }
}
```

Comment: @Sierra Updated answer for the commented snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking to list test1 and test2 separately, in which case the following would work:

```
for (var x in work["title"]) console.log(work["title"][x]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `title` in work, so `for(var x in work)` will iterate `title` and hence print `["test1", "test2"]`

```js
var work={ 
    "title": ["test1", "test2"]
}

for(var x in work) {
    console.log(work[x]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nobody mentioning `for (... of ...)` giving us the value and not the index

```js
let work = {'title': ['test1', 'test2']}

for (let x of work.title) {
  console.log(x);
}
```